# Error while connecting android app to remote mySQL database

Tags: java, android, mysql, raspberry-pi3

I made a very simple app just to stabilished a connection with my SQL database on Raspberry Pi with JDBC but when I tried to connect, the app give me a error, any suggest?

[image]

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.65:3306/myDB";
     private static final String user = "user";
     private static final String pass = "userpass";

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     public void connect(View v){
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        try{
             StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
               new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
             StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);

             if(con!=null){
                 tv.setText("Connection Successfully");
             }else
                 tv.setText("FAAAAIL ");

         }catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
               tv.setText(e.toString());
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You should never attach a mobile app directly to a database-  to do so you need to release your password in your app, which totally negates all the security of your database.  Instead you should use webservices, which will allow you to keep the password on your machine.

Comment: Regarding the error: probably either the port is blocked (check your firewall rules), mySQL does not allow remote connections or that user can't connect from that host. But seriously, unless this is just to test/prototype some thing, don't connect directly to the database. Anyone with your app will be able to retrieve the host, username and password, and do whatever that user has permissions to do!

Comment: I opened all the ports in my router and I opened the port 3306 on my rpi too, and still dont work. I am just testing connect this way @Salem